# WPF UI shows combobox items. The control says that they're empty

Tags: wpf, powershell, xaml

I'm losing my mind over this. I'm building a UI for a powershell script. The xaml for the combobox:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="CB_Failover" Width="172" Margin="5,5,0,0" IsReadOnly="True">
    <ComboBoxItem x:Name="CBI_CBFailover_ALL" Content="All"/>
    <ComboBoxItem x:Name="CBI_CBFailover_core" Content="Core"/>
    <ComboBoxItem x:Name="CBI_CBFailover_wave1" Content="Wave 1"/>
    <ComboBoxItem x:Name="CBI_CBFailover_wave2" Content="Wave 2"/>
    <ComboBoxItem x:Name="CBI_CBFailover_wave3" Content="Wave 3"/>
</ComboBox>
```

Once i run $synchash.window.showdialog() the items show up perfectly fine in the UI. However when i try to access the control for it, to make it useful. This is all I see.
$synchash.cb_failover

```
ShouldPreserveUserEnteredPrefix : 
IsEditable                      : 
Text                            : 
IsReadOnly                      : 
SelectionBoxItem                : 
SelectionBoxItemTemplate        : 
SelectionBoxItemStringFormat    : 
StaysOpenOnEdit                 : 
IsSelectionBoxHighlighted       : 
IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem   : 
SelectedIndex                   : 
SelectedItem                    : 
SelectedValue                   : 
SelectedValuePath               : 
Items                           : {, , , …}
etc...
```

the items property shows that there's items there, but they're all empty somehow. it's an array of nothing. if i go deeper into items ($synchash.CB_Failover.items) the properties for name and content is empty. I don't know from where the Combobox is getting the info for the UI. if not the control. But the UI shows the 'content' of each comboboxitem. I don't want to be too verbose and show my entire script, cause it's a lot. I'm hoping there's just some stupid property within combobox i need to add.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Still haven't figured out the issue - but it's caused by threading.
beginning of my script starts this in a new runspace.

```
$global:syncHash = [hashtable]::Synchronized(@{})
$syncHash.Host = $host;
$newRunspace =[runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
$newRunspace.ApartmentState = "STA"
$newRunspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"
$newRunspace.Open()    
$newRunspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("syncHash",$syncHash)

$psCmd = [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript({ 
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
$xamlFile = "a personal and private path that holds many secrets"
$inputXML = Get-Content $xamlFile -Raw
$inputXML = $inputXML -replace 'mc:Ignorable="d"', '' -replace "x:N", 'N' -replace '^<Win.*', '<Window'
[xml]$XAML = $inputXML
```

here's the kicker. If I do this through threading, the controls come through, just not with the content. Whether I build out all the variables automatically or manually - doesn't matter. $synchash will bring the control over, but not its content.

```
$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
$syncHash.Window=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )
#$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@*[contains(translate(name(.),'n','N'),'Name')]]") | % {
#    $syncHash.Add($_.Name, $syncHash.Window.FindName($_.name))
#}
$syncHash.Add('CB_Failover', $syncHash.Window.FindName('cb_failover'))
```

HOWEVER, if I don't create a new runspace, and just run it under a global scope, the content of the comboboxitems come through without issue.

```
$xamlFile = "A personal and private path"
$inputXML = Get-Content $xamlFile -Raw
$inputXML = $inputXML -replace 'mc:Ignorable="d"', '' -replace             
"x:N", 'N' -replace '^<Win.*', '<Window'
[xml]$XAML = $inputXML

$global:var_CB_Failover = $global:window.FindName('CB_Failover')
```

OUTPUT:

```
>$global:var_cb_failover.items.content
All    
Core
etc...
```

So why would a different thread be able to pull over the control, but not the contents from within that control. But, also, be able to pull that content and show it in the UI?

Answer (score 0):

So after digging around more - sorry, really new to all of this. Found an article written years ago with a solution by boe prox

https://learn-powershell.net/2012/10/14/powershell-and-wpf-writing-data-to-a-ui-from-a-different-runspace/

TLDR;

The content is there, but you can't pull it from another thread unless you use the dispatcher. In my case this worked.

```
$syncHash.CB_Failover.Dispatcher.Invoke([action]{$global:return = 
$syncHash.CB_Failover.items | select -Expand content}) | out-null
```

OUTPUT:

```
> $return
All
Core
etc...
```

It's just really really confusing because there's definitely a lot of other controls, content, etc that I can access without using the dispatcher.